# Usage of "bear fruit"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it a right usage for **bear fruit**?

> I hope it (our process) will bear fruit soon**.

And is it a right sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "I hope...will bear fruit soon" is fine. (assuming you are expecting some result, or even some fruit).  However, the "bare fruit" before it has a completely different meaning (fruit without any covering, like bare feet).